# twitter API unable to retrieve token

Tags: php, twitter

Hi I'm making an app which post tweets to users time lines after they have authenticated.  I'm using the library and tutorial found here : [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Everything works fine until I get to the callback url and attempt to retrieve the access token and a var dump of the request returns `Invalid request token` .

here's the code :

```
function authenicateApp() {

//Set app keys

// Connect to twitter and recive token
$connection = new TwitterOAuth('**', '**');
$temporary_credentials = $connection->getRequestToken('http://abc.def.com');

// Redirect to twitter authentation page
header('location:'.$connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials));
}

function appPost() {

$connection1 = new TwitterOAuth('**' ,'**', $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
var_dump($connection1->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993423/why-does-this-twitter-oauth-api-token-request-fail

Comment: @dseibert it's a significantly different question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually have `$temporary_credentials` to the session before you try and use the session when you create `$connection1`.